# Devise/Omniauth - How to deal with a Provider that doesn't include an email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, devise, omniauth

I have a Rails app that uses Devise and Omniauth to handle authentications. As prescribed I am receiving callbacks from the providers in my omniauth_callbacks_controller, where I check if the authentication already exists, and whether a user with the email given by the provider already exists, creating a new user if necessary.

I need a valid email for each user. My problem comes with callbacks from Twitter. Twitter doesn't provide an email for its users, so I can't create a valid user. To solve this I store the provider's data in a session and I send the user the new registrations page, asking them to submit their email address so I can create a valid user. When this form is submitted I hit a problem. The form has created a new user, but it is perfectly possible that a user with that email already exists (in which case I would need to add the authentication to that user).

At the moment I am checking to see if a user with the same email as the new user already exists. If so, I am ignoring the new user and applying the authentication to the user that already exists. However this feels really hacky.

How should I be doing this?

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def build_resource(*args)
    super
    if session[:omniauth]
      #If a user with this email already exists then use them instead
      existing_user = User.find_by_email(@user.email)
      if(existing_user)
          existing_user.email = @user.email
          @user = existing_user
      end
      #If there is a session available, we know it contains data for adding an authentication
      @user.apply_omniauth_data_as_authentication(session[:omniauth])
      #Ensure validations are passed on to next page
      @user.valid?
    end
  end
```

Comment: did you manage to fix this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Finnnn Just posted my Omniauth Callbacks controller in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. I'll try and remember where I got the fix from and post a link if I do:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  # This controller handles callbacks from Omniauth providers. If a user already exists with this provider we sign them in.
  # Otherwise we either add an authentication to the current user, or create a new user if one doesn't exist.

  def facebook
    authorize
  end

  def twitter
    authorize
  end

  private

    def authorize
      omniauth_data = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      #Check to see if we have an authentication for this provider already stored for any User
      authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth_data['provider'], omniauth_data['uid'])
      #If an authentication already exists, sign the owning User in
      if authentication
        flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully with " +  omniauth_data['provider'].titleize
        sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
      #Otherwise if there is a current User, add a new authentication for them
      elsif current_user
        current_user.authentications.create(:provider => omniauth_data['provider'], :uid => omniauth_data['uid'], :token => omniauth_data['token'])
        flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful"
        redirect_to user_profile_url
      #Otherwise we check if a user exists with the email address provided by the provider (if provided at all))
      else
        email = omniauth_data['info']['email']
        user = User.find_by_email(email)
        #If no user exists, create a new one
        if(!email || !user)
            user = User.new
        end
        user.apply_omniauth_data_as_authentication(omniauth_data)
        #If they save successfully (meaning we have enough data from the authorisation) sign them in
        if user.email?
          #We got all we needed from the provider so we don't need them to confirm'
          user.skip_confirmation!
          user.save!
          flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully with " +  omniauth_data['provider']
          sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
        #Otherwise we need to have the visitor manually submit missing information
        else
          #save the omniauth data in a session so we can add the authentication once registration is complete
          flash[:alert] = "Please complete registration"
          session[:omniauth] = omniauth_data.except('extra')
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
      end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution used by this link http://www.orhancanceylan.com/rails-twitter-and-facebook-authentications-with-omniauth-and-devise/

It uses the provider credentials to register in the normal devise process (as well as filling out provider and uid attributes on the user or on a separate table). Thus, when a new user tries to register using a provider, they will be required to put in an email and password, creating less headaches down the road (like wanting to log in the normal way, but not having a password to type in, and then you having to handle that).

While this solution somewhat negates the convenience of registering with social media the FIRST time, it creates long term beneficial effects with minimal effort.

If you absolutely do not want this kind of requirement for fear of losing signups or having your website seem less polished, find another solution and do all the work to handle those downstream cases.